# How to make a query with a custom order by parameter using array?

Tags: sql-server, django, python-3.x

I have an algorithm that outputs an array in a particular order. Example:

```
arr = [0, 1, 21, 2, 22, 23, 24, 25, 3, 27, 35, 36, 28, 37, 38, 4, 29, 5, 34, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

The array will be different depending on the user's input so the example above is only one of many undefined amount of possibilities; longer, shorter or different values (all values will be integers). So I wont be able to use `case` in my query.

I want to produce an SQL-Server query in my *views.py* to display all objects in my model in that exact order.

Here is my "query" at the moment but obviously it doesn't work.

```
test = QuoteAssemblies.objects.raw("""SELECT qmaQuoteAssemblyID,
                                             qmaPartID,
                                             qmaLevel,
                                             qmaPartShortDescription,
                                             qmaQuantityPerParent
                                      FROM QuoteAssemblies
                                      WHERE qmaQuoteAssemblyID IN arr
                                      ORDER BY qmaQuoteAssemblyID = arr""")
```

In essence I want the query to be ordered by `qmaQuoteAssemblyID` as long as it is in the same order of the array (not ASC, DESC etc).

```
qmaQuoteAssemblyID = 0
qmaQuoteAssemblyID = 1
qmaQuoteAssemblyID = 21
qmaQuoteAssemblyID = 2
etc...
```

There is a similar example for MySQL [Here](https://chriskief.com/2015/01/13/sort-django-query-order-by-using-values-within-in/). I just need something like that but for MSSQL. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your version of SQL Server supports JSON querying (i.e. 2016+), you can use `openjson()` function to number the elements of your array, and then use that number for sorting:

```
declare @Arr nvarchar(max) = '[0, 1, 21, 2, 22, 23, 24, 25, 3, 27, 35, 36, 28, 37, 38, 4, 29, 5, 34, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]';

SELECT q.qmaQuoteAssemblyID,
  q.qmaPartID,
  q.qmaLevel,
  q.qmaPartShortDescription,
  q.qmaQuantityPerParent
FROM dbo.QuoteAssemblies q
  inner join openjson(@Arr) ar on ar.[value] = q.qmaQuoteAssemblyID
ORDER BY ar.[key];
```

If you can't utilise JSON for this task, you will need to somehow produce a rowset with your array elements being correctly numbered, and use it in a similar fashion. There are lots of ways to achieve this, and it doesn't necessarily have to be done on server side. For example, you can create a 2 column `key-value` user-defined table type in your database, and provide the data as a parameter for your query.

Another approach is to supply the data in the form of XML, something like this:

```
declare @Ax xml = N'<r>
  <i n="0" v="0" />
  <i n="1" v="1" />
  <i n="2" v="21" />
  ...
</r>';

SELECT q.qmaQuoteAssemblyID,
  q.qmaPartID,
  q.qmaLevel,
  q.qmaPartShortDescription,
  q.qmaQuantityPerParent
FROM dbo.QuoteAssemblies q
  inner join @Ax.nodes('/r/i') ar(c) on ar.c.value('./@v', 'int') = q.qmaQuoteAssemblyID
ORDER BY ar.c.value('./@n', 'int');
```

Still, the numbering of XML nodes is better to be done by the application, as there is no efficient way to do this on the database side. That, and performance might be rather worse compared to the option 1.

Comment: This looks good. I will play around with it and see what I can get. However I am having trouble including a WHERE and AND condition `incorrect syntax near 'inner'`. WHERE [qmaQuoteID] = 'NING' AND [qmaQuoteLineID] = 1
inner join @Ax.nodes('/r/i') ar(c) on ar.c.value('./@v', 'int') = [qmaQuoteAssemblyID]
ORDER BY ar.c.value('./@n', 'int')

Comment: @Moms, the `where` clause should go after `from` (and all `join`s in it) and before `order by`.

Comment: I ended up using the second solution because I use sql-server 2012. Thanks for the help.